# Polmer.dart paper-dropdown-meu

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, material-design

I am having some trouble with paper-dropdown-menu
My html is:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu valueattr="label"> 
<core-menu class="menu">
    <paper-item label="Harold"></paper-item>
</core-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

It displays correctly initially when loading but after I click "Harold" it displays "0"

I have also tried 
<`paper-item>Harold<'/paper-item>

Any ideas?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As release of Polymer 0.5.1 [`paper-dropdown-menu`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-dropdown-menu) structure has changed a bit:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu>
  <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
    <core-menu class="menu">
      <paper-item name="Harold">Harold</paper-item>
    </core-menu>
  </paper-dropdown>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/MWalid/full/gbwwyR/)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I cannot find the import for paper-dropdown. It is not included in my paper elements packages. Where did you get it? Is it deprecated? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/ELpBUrgbEN8

Comment: @user1406416 it's not included in dart version yet.

Answer (score 1):

I look through the documentation more and found an answer that worked.

```
 <paper-dropdown-menu selected="Harold" valueattr="label">
     <paper-item label="Harold"></paper-item>
     </paper-dropdown-menu>
```